# Pandas dataframe plot not working with sparse data

Tags: pandas

I'm not sure even how to phrase this question so I'll post the dataframe and see if anyone can help.

I have various datafiles that I'm reading into a dataframe. The majority are sampled on the same grid and I'm using this as the index. However, one file is sampled on a finer grid. When I concatenate them all together it means I end up with fairly columns.

This is an example of the dataframe.

```
13.225                NaN            NaN         6.2791
13.259                NaN            NaN         6.1977
13.293                NaN            NaN         6.1451
13.300              0.771         1.0805            NaN
13.327                NaN            NaN         6.0669
13.361                NaN            NaN         5.9874
13.396                NaN            NaN         5.8977
13.400              0.761         1.0923            NaN
13.430                NaN            NaN         5.8264
13.465                NaN            NaN         5.7747
13.500              0.762         1.1347         5.7338
13.536                NaN            NaN         5.6613
```

As you can see, the first 2 columns are sampled at 13.3, 13.4,  13.5 etc but the last column is sampled more randomly.

When I try to plot this dataframe, only the final column is plotted. None of the values from the other columns appear at all in the plot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use `marker`:

```
df.set_index(0).plot(marker='o')
```

[image]